# Working with HMD and timeline in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d

I'm working with HMD and now I need to start with Unity. I want to make a scene like below. I have two character animation in which the first animation only visible to the left eye, and the second animation only visible to the right eye in HMD. It was all good.

[image]

When you see with both eye, two characters will overlap, but you can see it one by one by closing your other eye (yes, this is also part of my project). Then I need to make animation to swap the character, the rough illustration is below.

[image]

I tried to create a timeline and record it according to [Unity Timeline Tutorial on Youtube Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=42QZ3aUDnV0), so the first and second character will show for 3 seconds, and then I will swap the character in the same position as before for another 3 seconds. But the scene won't show like I expected. The previous character is still shown after the duration is over. Any suggestion ??

[image]

Comment: What i would suggest is to disable the Mesh Renderer of previous object at the end of the clip. Enable the renderer at the begining. Do the same for both of the objects. Enabled the  renderer of desired object at begining and disable renderer at the end of clip. This should solve your problem. Enabling/Disabling game object should also do same thing but if you have any scripts on the objects will be disabled so enabling/disabling renderer is better option

Comment: @killer_mech yes, I can't risk disabling my game object. I tried your suggestion to disable mesh renderer at the end of keyframe of the previous object too, doesn't seem to work as well.

Comment: What is happening can you post more details? Where are you disabling the mesh renderer? in script or Timeline? Coz timeline should work. I checked with simple cube. Check if anywhere it is getting enabled. It is better to post more update as i dont know what problem you are encountering now.

Comment: Ahh my mistake. I thought you were trying to play one animation for one side at a time. What I would suggest you to is combine the clips for 'Bino_reverese_left' Recorded and Recoreded(2) &&  'Bino_reverese_right' Recorded(1), Recorded(2) in one clip instead of two as first clip is overrides second one. I suspected somewhere it is overridden. You can ignore the disabling renderer. It is not necessary. Basically give swapping position after 3 seconds in one clip and let the clips play in loop. This should solve the problem.

Comment: Note: Do not create multiple instances of animation of same gameobject. Only the first one will be used it seems.

Comment: @killer_mech Hi, I followed your suggestion to combine the clips. Works like a charm ! Please put your suggestion on the answer section so I can accept it. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer must be already be clear to everyone by now going through comments sections above but here is the complete answer. OP wanted to swap the animation at the end of 3 seconds and swap them with each other. He used Timeline feature of unity.

Note: I have never used timeline before so I went through a quick setup to check how timeline animations affect the positions of the objects in timeline and animation positions are updated based on its keyframe values.

Timeline is basically uses animator so here what happened was single game object had two states of animation. The first timeline state after finishing was overriding the second timeline state and the position of gameobject was taken from first timeline animation which kept it at initial value only.

Solution to this was merging the two animation timeline states into one as the value of position will be overridden in same timeline for the object. 
ie after 3 second the position of 'gameobject A' will go from X to Y instead of remaining static at X as first timeline animation would be overriding to X only instead of X->Y

Comment: Hi @killer_mech, I've contacted you via chat.stackoverflow regarding this question. Would you please check my message ? Thanks.